# jQuery Flash version and size detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have a bit of a weird problem that i have been bashing my head against the wall for two days now.

I need to check what flash version an uploaded flash file is, what the size of the flash file is and what dimensions its using. Also need to find out what Action Script version its using with j Query or java script

I have no idea to go about this and the Google's lets me down because i just get results for flash file up loaders :-|

Please can someone assist me

I have tried building a hook for the j Query flash plugin but to no avail

[EDIT] I forgot to mention this will have to be done automatically, around 30 flash files gets loaded a day and would like a java script script to handle the validation for me

Answer (score 0):

download and install Adobe SWF Investigator, it should be able to tell you everything about the swf you need to know.
http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/swfinvestigator/

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention this is files that they uploaded to my webserver. It will be way too much to do it manually because there are around 30 getting loaded a day